# Disable scrolling by the full section

Tags: javascript

I have an EventListener make the website scroll by full section

```
document.body.addEventListener(
      "touchmove",
      function(t) {
        t.preventDefault(),
          e.scrollLock ||
            ((e.deltaY = e.startY - t.touches[0].clientY),
            (e.deltaX = e.startX - t.touches[0].clientX),
            Math.abs(e.deltaY) > Math.abs(e.deltaX) &&
              (e.deltaY > 3 &&
                !e.isAnimating &&
                e.currSection + 1 < e.sections.length &&
                ((e.isAnimating = !0),
                e.getSection(e.currSection + 1),
                e.sectionTitle.getSection(e.currSection + 1)),
              e.deltaY < -3 &&
                !e.isAnimating &&
                e.currSection - 1 >= 0 &&
                ((e.isAnimating = !0),
                e.getSection(e.currSection - 1),
                e.sectionTitle.getSection(e.currSection - 1))));
      },
      { passive: !1 }
    ),
```

I need to disable this and make it scroll normally.

Comment: ... just remove it?

Comment: I tried, but the same issue the normal scroll not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function works for me

```
$('#elementid').on('touchmove', function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it dynamically only for certain circumstances you can try it with calling:

```
document.body.removeEventListener(type, listener[, options])
```

Here's a good read on [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

From the docs:

> The EventTarget.removeEventListener() method removes from the EventTarget an event listener previously registered with EventTarget.addEventListener(). The event listener to be removed is identified using a combination of the event type, the event listener function itself, and various optional options that may affect the matching process; see Matching event listeners for removal

Syntax:

> target.removeEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
>
> target.removeEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);

Where `type` is your string which specifies the type of event for which to remove an event listener and `listener` is your EventListener-function of the event handler to remove from the event target.

If you want to remove it alltogether - just comment it out or delete it in your code as suggested in the comments..

Comment: mainly I need to activate a scroll inside a child div in one of the sections, but this script prevents it and change all of the section, I tried to remove it, but the same issue the normal scroll not working.